# Why did Lady Lisa become human in Pixels?

Tags: pixels

In the movie Pixels, one pixel alien takes the look of Lady Lisa, on which Ludlow had a huge crush. But no other pixel aliens looked like actual figures, they all appeared pixelated. Why did only Lady Lisa become looking like a living human being?

Comment: Because you don't cast Ashley Benson and then have her covered in pixels